# Turning a sympy expression into a vector to find linearly independent subset

Tags: sympy

I have a list of expressions like `4.0*x[0] + 5.0*x[10] + 1 = 0`
I would like to turn these into vectors according to the coefficients like `[4.0, 0, 0, ..., 5.0, ... , 1]`. The reason is that some of my equations may be linearly dependent and I want to run QR from the numpy library so I can find a linearly independent subset.

I can get the constant term by doing `expr.replace(x[i], 0)` with `i` a wildcard index. I can also get most of the other terms by `expr.atoms(Mul)` which gives me the set `4.0*x[0], 5.0*x[10]` and then for each of these expressions I can do `expr.atoms(Indexed).pop()` and `expr.atoms(Float).pop()` to split the parts.

The trouble is when I have an expression like `x[0] + 5.0*x[10] + 1 = 0`, where the first variable appears with an implicit coefficient of `1`. The term is no longer recognized as a `Mul` object.

In any case, I think there might be a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Do you have a list of all the possible symbols `x[i]` that you use in your code? Or does that need to be derived from the expression too?

Comment: can't you convert first 4.0*x[0] + 5.0*x[10] + 1  to  4y+5y^9 +1 by taking x =[1, 'y', 'y^2, ... ]  ?

Comment: The only variable that appears is `x`. It's type is `IndexedBase`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give your symbols a specific order, as in the code below, you could convert the expression to a polynomial and get its coefficients:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
>>> a1, a2, a3, a4 = symbols('a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]')
>>> used_symbols = (a1, a2, a3, a4)
>>> replacements = [(n, x**(enu+1)) for enu,n in enumerate(used_symbols)]
>>> expr = 5 + a1 + 4*a4
>>> Poly(expr.subs(replacements)).all_coeffs()
[4, 0, 0, 1, 5]
```

And you could retrieve a list of the used symbols too if they are not known beforehand with the following recursive function:

```py
def retrieve_used_symbols(expr):
    """Return the symbols used in the `expr` in a list."""
    used_symbols = []
    for term in expr.args:
        if term.is_Atom and term.is_Symbol:
            used_symbols.append(term)
        else:
            used_symbols.extend(retrieve_used_symbols(term))
    return used_symbols
```

The latter comes in handy when you have mixed symbols:

```py
>>> crazy_expr = expr + 10*y-2*z
>>> crazy_expr
a[1] + 4*a[4] + 10*y - 2*z + 5
>>> used_symbols = retrieve_used_symbols(crazy_expr)
>>> replacements = [(n, x**(enu+1)) for enu,n in enumerate(used_symbols)]
>>> Poly(crazy_expr.subs(replacements)).all_coeffs()
[4, -2, 1, 10, 5]
>>> list(reversed(used_symbols))
[a[4], z, a[1], y]
```

For an IndexedBase object, it's even simpler:

```py
coeffs = [expr.coeff(x[i]) for i in range(10)]
```

But you'll still need to add the constant term, which, like you said, you can obtain from a wildcard substitution:

```py
ind = Wild('i')
constant_term = expr.replace(x[ind], 0)
```

Comment: Your last comment about using `.coeff` was actually the most helpful for me! Thanks!

Comment: @Mark notice that I edited in that last part only after it became clear that your symbols were `IndexedBase` objects. I felt the first part was still useful for others so didn't remove it either. Glad you found it now, though.

Comment: instead of used_free_symbols you can do expr.free_symbols; and to get the addititve constant (the rational terms) with expr.as_coeff_Add()[0]

Comment: @smichr Wonderful! I'd convert that into an answer if I were you. You'll get my vote.

Answer (score 2):

{as requested by @(Oliver W.)}

Given

```
>>> x = IndexedBase('x')
>>> eqs = 4*x[0] + 5*x[5] + 1, x[1] - x[2]
>>> v = list(ordered(Tuple(*eqs).atoms(Indexed)))
```

One could do it like this

```
>>> [[eq.coeff(vi) for vi in v] + [eq.as_coeff_Add()[0]] for eq in eqs] 
[[4, 0, 0, 5, 1], [0, 1, -1, 0, 0]]
```

But much of this is available through the matrix method `jacobian`. But to use it you have to replace the x[i] with symbols (since diff only works with functions are symbols, IIRC):

```
>>> d = [Dummy() for vi in v]
>>> z = dict(zip(d, [0]*len(d)))
>>> m = Matrix([eq.xreplace(dict(zip(v, d))) for eq in eqs])
>>> m.jacobian(d)
Matrix([
[4, 0,  0, 5],
[0, 1, -1, 0]])
>>> m.subs(z)
Matrix([
[1],
[0]])
```

Comment: Glad you added it and with two different approaches even. +1